# Compute the runtime of the function

Tags: java, runtime

> Compute the runtime in Θ(·) notation as a function of N.

```
public static void p5(int N) {
  for (int i = 1; i <= N * N; i *= 2) { 
     for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) { 
          System.out.println("moo"); 
     } 
  } 
 }
```

To do that I started to compute the runtime for several values of N.

N=1
C(N)=1 since j = only 0

N=2 C(N) = 7 since  j = 0 for i = 1, j = 0,1 for i = 2, j = 0,1,2,3 for i = 4

N = 3 C(N) = 15 since j = 0 for i = 1, j = 0,1 for i = 2, j = 0,1,2,3 for i = 4,
j = 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7 for i = 8

So, there is a pattern:

C(1) = 1 = 2^0

C(2) = 7 = 2^0 + 2^1 + 2^2

C(3) = 15 = 2^0 + 2^1 +2^2 + 2^3

C(4) = 31 = 2^0 + 2^1 +2^2 + 2^3 + 2^4

C(N) = 2^0 + 2^1 +2^2 + 2^3 + 2^4 + … + 2^N = 2^(N+1) - 1

So, I get Θ(2^N) as answer!
However, the answer is N^2.

Can you help me to understand where is the problem?

Comment: tip: solve the problem for `M = N * N`.

Comment: @Turing85 I think I did that, didn't I? For every value of N up to N*N I computed how many times the println will be called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complexity of `p5` is actually `O(n^2)`, you can compute it formally; or simply edit the method so that it returns the count of cycles performed; and compute the ratio `ops/(N^2)` to prove that. The code below dumps the output:

```
p5 N=1 took op=1 operations, ratio=1,000000
p5 N=2 took op=7 operations, ratio=1,750000
p5 N=4 took op=31 operations, ratio=1,937500
p5 N=8 took op=127 operations, ratio=1,984375
p5 N=16 took op=511 operations, ratio=1,996094
p5 N=32 took op=2047 operations, ratio=1,999023
#etc..
```

and the code:

```
package sample;
public class SampleComplexity {
  public static int p5(int N) {
    int res = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= N * N; i *= 2) {
      for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        //count operations here
        res++;
      }
    }
    return res;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int N=1;
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++) {
      int p5 = p5(N);
      System.out.printf("p5 N=%d took op=%d operations, ratio=%f%n", N, p5, 1.*p5/N/N);
      N=N*2;
    }
  }
}
```